# Compile time checking for division by 0 in Swift

Tags: swift, compile-time, divide-by-zero

Why does `print(1.0 / 0)` return `inf` while `print(0.0 / 0)` returns NaN and `print(0 / 0)` fails at compile time?

It seems that Swift has compile time checking for integers divided by 0 but not for floats/doubles?

Can anybody explain why this is the case?

Answer (score 2):

The IEEE 754 standard for floating-point numbers and their arithmetic defines "infinity" and "not a number" as valid values. They may not be "valid" in the sense of mathematically useful... but they're what the standard defines. Code that works with floating-point numbers *expects* those values from certain operations, and can check for / react to them if need be, so Swift respects the standard for FP math.

There isn't a corresponding cross-language, CPU-independent standard for integer arithmetic. Outside of Swift, it's generally assumed that dividing integers by zero is a [Bad Thing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jyaLZHiJJnE), because you don't necessarily know if it'll halt the program or produce an incorrect result.

Swift's default behavior is to be "safe" for all integer arithmetic, so any operation that would overflow the bounds of the type results in a runtime exception. (That includes division by zero.)

When you put `0 / 0` in literal code, you get a *compile time* error because Swift performs arithmetic on constants at compile time. (If you have code like `let x = 1 + 2`, it doesn't make sense to compute the resulting `3` at run time because it's constant for all runs of your program.)